# Synchronizing Customer between CRM and AX

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I am configuring MS Dynamics connector for synchronising MS CRM 2011 and MS AX 2012.
It has been working fine with some Entities, but I cannot get the Account to work.
I have enabled the Address during the configuration and I can sync Customer Services with their Adresses into CRM's account, but not the other way around.

I have enabled the tracing for the connector and here is the error I get:

```
12/17/2013 14:21:27: task 2a6bcf1c-d62a-4f5d-af04-a465d48eb61f is WaitingToRun
12/17/2013 14:21:27: task 2a6bcf1c-d62a-4f5d-af04-a465d48eb61f is Running
12/17/2013 14:21:27: RetryTask starts execution. This is RetryTask attempt 3.
VERBOSE TID:TP-33 [2013-12-17T15:21:27.6853306+01:00]: [Retry : Retry key : [999999999911, e3187a8a-2567-e311-9f44-0050569239ef]] has started to read.
VERBOSE TID:TP-33 [2013-12-17T15:21:27.6853306+01:00]: Making "Retrieve" request on entity "" with conditions "" to CRM.
WARNING TID:TP-50 [2013-12-17T15:21:30.9146341+01:00]: An unrecognized exception was thrown [mscorlib::0x80131501].
ERROR TID:TP-50 [2013-12-17T15:21:30.9146341+01:00]: [Account to Customer Service] has encountered an error while reading records. Processing will be aborted. Error text: A record level exception has occurred for record [999999999912, 10d0bb3d-2667-e311-9f44-0050569239ef]. Error text : Request Failed. See the Exception Log for details.
    --- Exception Dump --- 
    Caught Exception: [Microsoft.Dynamics.Integration.Service.Tasks.RecordException] A record level exception has occurred for record [999999999912, 10d0bb3d-2667-e311-9f44-0050569239ef]. Error text : Request Failed. See the Exception Log for details.
    Stack trace:


    Inner Exception: [System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[schemas.microsoft.com.dynamics._2008._01.documents.Fault.AifFault]] Request Failed. See the Exception Log for details.
    Stack trace:

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ConnCustomerOrgService.create(ConnCustomerOrgServiceCreateRequest request)
   at ConnCustomerOrgServiceClient.create(CallContext CallContext, AxdConnCustomerOrg ConnCustomerOrg)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Integration.Adapters.AX2012.DynamicServiceObjectProviderBase.WriteObject(Object value)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Integration.Service.Tasks.RecordWork.DoRecordWork(DbMap map, Object key, OperationType operationType, DateTime startTime, String loggingSourceName)


task Account to Customer Service log event : Warning ...
task 6ef94c7f-a5cf-46bc-8be6-93fb2f06dc80 retry at 12/17/2013 14:21:30.
task Account to Customer Service progress at 100% ...
```

How is it possible to solve it?

Comment: I have not used the connector but this line looks suspicious...`Making "Retrieve" request on entity "" with conditions "" to CRM`

Comment: I  am applying no Filter so it is normal that there is no condition. I guess the Entity is empty also cause I am running it for all the Entities

Comment: Is there some message in the windows error viewer on the AOS server? The message you posted point you to the "Exception log" for details.

Comment: I took the message from the Connector log file. Is there a section in the Event Viewer of the AX server where I could find a better description? I have been through it, but I cannot find it

Comment: see [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834351.aspx)